# Nginx-WordPress conf

Tags: bash, linux, wordpress, configuration, nginx

This is how I create am Nginx virtual host for a WordPress webapp. I did best to keep it as minimal as I can while having a working webapp. Please review it:

```
#!/bin/bash
domain="$1" && test -z "$domain" && exit 2
drt="/var/www/html" 

cat <<-EOF > "$s_a/$domain.conf"
    server {
        root ${drt}/${domain};
        server_name ${domain} www.${domain};
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }
        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
            expires 365d;
        }
    }
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your `server_name` to be `$domain` and `www.$domain`. What if, someone puts in `www.example.com` for the script argument? You will thne be serving `www.example.com` and `www.www.example.com`. Instead; replace possible `www.` from the `domain` variable.

```
domain="${domain#www\.}"
```

Each of your `location` section has a different indentation. Keep it consistent. Since `server` section is the root level, you do not need to indent it out. I understand that you are flushing the left indentation from the `conf`, but I would suggest keeping it, since one might want to peek at them in future, and would like to tweak it?

---

```
#!/bin/bash
domain="$1" && test -z "$domain" && exit 2
domain="${domain#www\.}"
drt="/var/www/html" 

cat <<EOF > "$s_a/$domain.conf"
server {
    root "${drt}/${domain}";
    server_name ${domain} www.${domain};
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~* \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
}

EOF
```

Comment: Hi, thanks ! Please elaborate on "Each of your location section has a different indentation. Keep it consistent".

Comment: @user9303970 What I meant was, two of your `location` sections have a 4-space further indented closing `}`, whereas the last one doesn't.

Comment: Oh yes, this is a mistake and I found myself a few days ago and fixed. Good you noted that anyway.

Comment: It was important for me inident the `server` in this case because the heredocument will de-indent it in execution. It will de-indent everything in exeuction to be honest, due to the hyphen in `<<-`.

Comment: which is why I mentioned: "_I understand that you are flushing the left indentation from the conf, but I would suggest keeping it, since one might want to peek at them in future, and would like to tweak it?_"

Comment: Yes, I keep it only for comfortability of read, but of course, it's highly subjective.